# React-Native alignItems: "flex-end" does not work inside an <Image> tag

Tags: android, user-interface, reactjs, react-native, native

I have a TouchableOpacity contained inside an Image which I am using to present a background for my application.

The issue is when I'm trying to align my TouchableOpacity to something like center or flex-end it does not work inside an Image tag. The TouchableOpacity simply disappears...

Demonstration of the issue:

[image]

Here I tried with a View instead of an Image It works...
[image]

Comment: did you tried `alignSelf:'flex-end'` ?

Comment: Did you even read or look at the question and image? Or the answer right below?

Comment: I am saying you need to add this property to the `View` placed inside <image> tag or you should place the image tag inside a view and provide alignItems:'center'

Comment: Yes. I did add this, however, for Image tags, we are required to set width and height to null or undefined. Otherwise flex-end simply doesn't work. Please refer to my answer below. It seems to me you just didn't read the question, nor looked at the pictures or answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised the issue.

Must set:

```
width: null,
height: null,
```

to the Image tag.